# How to return data from array like this with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

For example, I have JavaScript array like this:

```
var data = [
{text:'Business', aid:'6'}, 
{text:'Careers', aid:'29'}, 
{text:'Credits', aid:'28'}, 
{text:'Insurance', aid:'30'}
];
```

Now, in URl is passed ID and I need to grab 'text' from this array based on that ID like:

```
$('#category').val(data, function(item) {return item.aid['6'].text;} ); // = Business
```

So I want to populate form field #category with text from array based on passed URL ID = aid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `filter`*<sup>[[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)]</sup>* method to get the right object:

```
var aid = 28,
    match = data.filter(function(elem) { return elem.aid == aid; });

if (match.length) {
    $('#category').val(match[0].text);
}
```

Comment: Hi @FishBasketGordo Just discovered that IE8 makes error like: "Message: Object doesn't support this property or method". Could You advice me what to do? Thanks

Comment: Found solution, just changed to this: 
match = $.grep(data,function(elem){ return elem.aid == aid; });